# running docker container without /bin/bash command

Tags: docker

I create docker container with

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

in book The docker book I read

> The container only runs for as long as the command we specified, /bin/bash , is running.

didn't I created terminal with option -it and /bin/bash isn't required? will anything change if I don't pass any command in docker run?

Answer (score 2):

You will get the same behavior if you run

```
sudo docker run -it ubuntu
```

because the `ubuntu` docker image specifies `/bin/bash` as the default command. You can see that in the [`ubuntu` Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/451851eab04432157249eb444d5a42714e2a7112/focal/Dockerfile#L42). As @tadman wrote in their answer, providing a command (like `/bin/bash`) overrides the default `CMD`.

In addition, `-it` does not imply a bash terminal. `-t` allocates a pseudo-tty, and `-i` keeps STDIN open even if not attached. See the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground) for further details.

Answer (score 1):

That's an override to the default `CMD` specification. You can run a container with defaults, that's perfectly normal, but `/bin/bash` is a trick to pop open a shell so you can walk around and check out the built container to see if it's been assembled and configured correctly.